# Importing Delimiter Separated Values with pandas for "indented" table

Tags: python, pandas, import, python-import

I am working in my thesis project and I need to analyze the data in a .dat file that was generated by a FORTRAN program. I would rather not modify the original program, because it was made by my advisor. The file is an N by N table that has the following format:

```
..
  3.57999980395659056E-01  3.56725977862117904E-01  3.40374191936946680E-01
  3.22943610909491363E-01  3.43143848106836513E-01  3.32229122795851706E-01
  3.25043838439847577E-01  3.31033248287544712E-01  3.36685762611352801E-01
```

The two dots are not included in the file, I placed them there to show that every line is indented by two spaces. I am importing these data with the pandas package:

```
df = pd.read_csv("pathname", sep="\s\s")
```

The problem is that the first row of data is not being imported: when I checked the values of the imported matrix I got:

```
>>> df.values[1][1]
0.3310332482875447
```

Which should be the value of the `[2][1]` component, not the `[1][1]` (and indeed the matrix has 255 rows and 256 columns, when the original file is a square of 256 by 256). I suspect the problem comes from the indentation of the first column. I would like to know if there is a solution that does not require me to modify the files manually (there are 4000 of them for every simulation) and preferably that it uses the pandas package (because it is very convenient and simple to use).

Comment: `df = pd.read_csv("pathname", sep="\s+ ", engine="python")`?

Comment: Ahh, I did not know that `\s` stood for a single character space. Why do you use a "+ "? Is it adding a space afterwards? Or is it something else?

Comment: Yes, it considers all consecutive white spaces as on delimiter. If you don’t have `+`, ` ` will be considered as two delimiters, and you will get an `NaN` in between.

Comment: I have modified the code with your suggestion (although I later changed it to `\s\s`  so that I did not need the instruction `engine="python"`) but it still has the same problem. I will modify the question to change that detail.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't realize  that you were talking about first row of data. Then pass `header=None` into `read_csv`.

Comment: Ahh that solved the problem perfectly, thank you very much. If you wish you could post that as an answer so that I can up-vote and accept it.

Comment: nvm that, happy coding.